# i have tried to justified my text in android studio but i got error in line 16 (webView.loadData), here is my java code

Tags: android-studio, webview

```
package com.example.user.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String htmlText = " %s ";


        String myData = "hhhhhhh.";

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);

        webView.loadData(String.format(htmlText, myData), "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will

        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long

        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Also, try to format your code correctly for this site, you just need to put 4 spaces on all of the code.

Comment: @ Yuri-M-Dias , the error in this line (webView.loadData(String.format(htmlText, myData), "text/html", "utf-8");)